# Flutter project - All files duplicated when created

Tags: android, flutter

Whenever I create a Flutter project either by using the Flutter CLI or Android Studio, a strange problems seem to occur. All files are duplicated and a ' 2' (space two) is put in the end of the file's name.

Take a look:
[image]

This prevents my project from being compiled and it's really annoying to see all these duplicated file. How to fix this issue?

**build.gradle android version:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
```

**gradle.properties:**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Probably you are using same name and same location for the project. Did you tried to change the project location or a different name for your project ?

Comment: Already did it, and unfortunately it's not working

Comment: how are you creating your project? using android studio or using a command from your terminal

Comment: i tried via terminal and via android studio. in both ways, the same problem is happening

Comment: So if you build a new project `my_other_flutter_app`, it will also have duplicate files?

Comment: @JesseLawson yes, unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

have you ever copied any files locally ?
in my case i did and then this happened, what i have done is deleted the file then created a branch locally, then push it remotely.

Initialize Git Repository Locally:

```
 git init
```

Checkout to required branch:

```
 git checkout -b <branch-name>
```

Add and Commit Your Project Files:

```
 git add .
```

Check git status then commit

```
git status

git commit -m "Initial commit”:
```

Add the GitLab Repository as Remote:

```
 git remote add origin <your-repository-url>
```

Pull if required

hint:        `git config pull.rebase false`  # merge
hint:        `git config pull.rebase true`   # rebase
hint:        `git config pull.ff only`       # fast-forward only

Push Your Project to GitLab:

```
git push origin <branch-name>
```

Comment: Already 3 years since I made this question, so I don't remember exactly why this happened, but, if I'm not mistaken, it happened because iCloud sync was active in that folder. Turning iCloud sync off solved the problem